# Why is my SharePoint account is not listed in Stack Exchange list of sites?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, openid

I have accounts on Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, etc.
They appear in my Stack Exchange profile.

However, this is not the case for [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/about).

Why?

I guess this is related to an OpenID issue (I previously logged in using Facebook, but as many customers disable it, I started to log in using Google).

Can you check please?

I am not sure if it's related, but in Stack Exchange I see I joined Meta Stack Overflow four months ago and have 208 reputation; today I "see" only 101.

[edit] I'm quite sure now my accounts are messed concerning the OpenID I used.
Is there any way to clean, reattach, merge, etc. all my accounts with my main OpenID provider (Google) and Facebook as the alternative OpenID provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged your duplicate meta accounts (you had one facebook and one google OpenId, each on different accounts).

You'll now see all the sites linked in your [local](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163519/steve-b?tab=accounts) and [network](https://stackexchange.com/users/9b4c9c40-3cd3-4717-bb0f-9432f980656b?tab=accounts) profiles as a result.

Comment: this seems to have solved my problem. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You've got duplicated MSO accounts. This one and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156328/steve-b (which has 208) rep but no linked accounts.

I'm not a mod so can't see the details but I would suspect you've managed to log in with different OpenIDs